# Size of UIView object in Interface Builder changes when using the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I have an extra UIView object that I just dragged onto the storyboard. It covers the entire iPhone screen. So I clicked on it and dragged it until it only covered half of the iPhone screen.

This is what my storyboard looks like with my extra UIView object selected:

[image]

However, when I actually use the app on my iPhone, the UIView is much smaller and doesn't even take up half of the screen(It's the square with the stackoverflow site image inside of it):

[image]

How can I keep it from being smaller when I actually run the app? When running the app, I want the UIView object to be the same size as it is on the storyboard in xcode.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `setBackgroundColor` to `UIView` and check frame. How u r setting Image to UIView? R u using `colorWithImagePattern`?

Comment: More info can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847921/need-to-change-size-and-location-of-calayer-class-objects

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You must have selected Autolayout. Uncheck it and problem is resolved.

Comment: It's not auto layout. Already tried that. It has something to do with using AVFoundation and the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.

Comment: well, I can't see if you mentioned that earlier.

Comment: Yeah sorry I had created a different post.